# ¿Cómo hago para sacar los números positivos y negativos?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

¿Cómo hago para sacar los números positivos y negativos?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[7], b[7], c[7], i, k=0, h=0;
 
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nIngrese a["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
     
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
            {b[k]=a[i];k++;}
        else
            {c[h]=a[i];h++;}
    }

    cout<<"\nLos pares son:";
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        cout<<"\nb["<<i<<"]="<<b[i];

    cout<<"\nLos impares son:";
    for(i=0;i<h;i++)
        cout<<"\nc["<<i<<"]="<<c[i];

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente tienes que introducir un bucle `if-else` dentro del `for` de la forma

```
if (a[i] < 0)
    cout<<"El numero"<<a[i]<<"es negativo"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"El numero"<<a[i]<<"es positivo"<<endl;
```

De esta forma, puedes discernir entre los número menores que 0 (negativos) y los que son mayores o iguales que cero (positivos).
En este ejemplo he determinado que el número 0 sea positivo.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Un número negativo tendrá un valor menor a cero. Y un código [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) bien redactado:

- **No usa la cabecera `<conio.h>`**: Esa cabecera es del lenguaje C y no debe usarse en C++.
- **No incluye cabeceras que no usa**: La cabecera `<conio.h>` además de ser de otro lenguaje, no estás usando ninguna de las funcionalidades que proporciona.
- **Usa variables con nombres autoexplicativos**: Al leer el nombre de una variable, debemos ser capaces de deducir para que se va a usar en el código; eso no sucede con nombres como `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `k`, `h`.
- **Define las variables cerca de donde se usan**: No hay necesidad de definir las variables que indexan un bucle `for` fuera del bucle.

Si redactamos bien tu programa, podría parecerse a este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    constexpr int tamanyo = 7;
    int numeros[tamanyo];

    list<int> pares, impares, positivos, negativos;

    for (int indice = 0; indice != tamanyo; ++indice)
    {
        cout << "\nIngrese el numero [" << indice << "] = ";
        cin >> numeros[indice];

        (numeros[indice] % 2 ? impares : pares).push_back(numeros[indice]);
        (numeros[indice] < 0 ? negativos : positivos).push_back(numeros[indice]);
    }

    cout << "\nLos numeros pares son:\n";
    for (const int &numero : pares)
        cout << numero << ' ';

    cout << "\nLos numeros impares son:\n";
    for (const int &numero : impares)
        cout << numero << ' ';

    cout << "\nLos numeros positivos son:\n";
    for (const int &numero : positivos)
        cout << numero << ' ';

    cout << "\nLos numeros negativos son:\n";
    for (const int &numero : negativos)
        cout << numero << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLJTsMwED1nvmIogjYqQV0OSE0azkj8QVtVJjXBIhlHsYNAqN8e7MRJUcVS1afRLG@ZcVIUQZIxSuv6UlCSVTuOkZBKl5zlMRxymVA6BhCkMWeCRj58glcpQSkSy7kqWMJR6V0I4CWSlObvRYm2XbOc0YfEJd6F4NkMVTkvpVq5ysbOWPzIFGMsWMnVDYrcBYVUQos3aULiKWtCO/EsSxxZOEE7YciXOAm7@GLZ0YY4HrdJHzwj2YirNEYRDtb0QKlh4MgzJwlXA1tyILZpY2AHoR0ThHHcS29bGuXe6CiJVzjD@84ALlpH/m1RqZftE0tejwf88CeUCCcGpbdscbpN/IO1b27Q23w0w66rlYJK0mJN1lezxOZeza2u3R46zd/25SomGuIw/J2hs30Ch2s9h6VfxUle@r2dwXQ4wAlMffNfTGheyXVVkvmxsK/rYA7BDIIpTGAKM5jDFw)</kbd>.